# Why excel is doing multiple selection if I select a column?

Tags: excel

I am facing this issue on my excel sheet, If I am selecting a column by pressing on column number from top, there has been multiple selection happen across the same column as shown below

[image]

Because of this, I cannot drag and drop values to next column or paste values to any other column.
Can someone help me over here why this is happening and how to stop excel from doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be working with filtered data. I've created a very simple column, containing the entries 'a', 'b', 'a' and 'a' again. I filtered on 'a', selected the remaining data and this is what I got:

[image]

If you don't want this but you want to select/copy the entire column, you need to stop filtering.

When you copy/paste values, only the filtered once get copied, as you can see from the following screenshot:

[image]

Explanation: when copying to another row (starting from "A7"), the three 'a's get copied, not the 'b'.
When copying to another column (starting from "C1"), the three 'a's get copied (into cells "C2", "C3" and "C4"), but obviously, as row "3" is filtered out, you don't see the content of "C3".

Comment: Hi, yeah you are correct. I was working on filtered data. Is there any way to copy filtered cells only or drag and drop only filtered cells to next column ?

Comment: @ShajiThornBlue: I edited my answer accordingly. If you want to copy the cells on their respective rows, you'll need to remove the filter first.